# Moving from material to texture, how do I keep diffuse/specular settings?

Tags: texturing, materials

The sole purpose of my models is to export them into a game engine (Unity).

I model in low poly with flat shading, and the goal is to be able to use a simple color palette to be shared among all models in the game.

I'm inspired by this guide: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/go-beyond-retro-pixel-art-with-flat-shaded-3d-in-unity--gamedev-12259

It suggests unwrapping and then moving the faces over to the right color:

[image: Texture map]

Can I somehow make this color palette automatically or do I have to make it in an image editor? Or can I perhaps make it manually in blender (the next best thing)?

My real question is, though, how do I keep everything from getting super specular, as textures are wont to do? How do I get my diffuse/specular settings over into the texture?

Complete beginner at this, as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make color palette automatically through scripting in both unity and blender, but with given info and case it's beyond the scope of this question. You can create texture manually in blender through setting UV/Image view from *view* to *paint*, creating new 2px*2px image, and painting it with brush with radius 1.

For your other question, there is no simple automatic way to put unity-compatible specular data into your texture. The specularity behaviour depends purely of the choice of the shader and supplied textures in unity, and without further info it's hard to say much about how to proceed with that and also it's not really blender-related question, so you need to go look for unity-related tutorials and forums.

> To get the look in that tutorial you need to switch your material's shader in Unity from standard to Legacy > Diffuse

Comment: There's no such thing as a specular map to send with the model?

Comment: None that i'd be aware of. Also, as you have not stated what kind of shader you are using or what kind of result you are hoping to achieve, there's not even way to know what kind of specular map you are going to need.

Comment: I see. This is more complicated than I thought, but at least I know now what not to search for!